# Jersey - how to continue with next servlet filter on 404?

Tags: java, servlets, jersey, servlet-filters

I'd like to use Jersey (3.1.3) to filter http requests at endpoint */x* as follows:

- if */x* exists: serve the request,
- if */x* does not exist: continue with the next servlet filter in the chain that may handle */x*

The whole works when setting *property(ServletProperties.FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404, true)*. But, as soon as I add an *jakarta.ws.rs.ext.ExceptionMapper* as resource, the request gets aborted and upcoming servlet filters are not executed.

Has anybody a solution of my problem?

Sidemark: Looking at the Jersey sources, I'm looking for a way to handle the *NotFoundException* thrown in *org.glassfish.jersey.server.ServerRuntime* in case that no endpoint has been found - before calling the *ExceptionMapper* which effectively aborts the request. I tried also *ServerProperties.RESPONSE_SET_STATUS_OVER_SEND_ERROR* but this doesn't seem to be relevant here.

Comment: Every filter is supposed to call the next one in the chain. If you do that, it'll work as you expect.

Comment: As far as I know, each servlet filter can decide to call the next filter via chain.doFilter() or not. I my case, I declared two servlet filters (first jersey filter, then another filter) in web.xml, both matching on url-pattern /*. When requesting a non-existing endpoint, the jersey filter is always executed, but the second filter runs only if the FILTER_FORWARD_ON_404 property has been set to true and no ExceptionMapper is registered.